# Added date filtering component to morris charts

Tags: javascript, morris.js

I am using morris chart using http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/bars.html

one of the key problem i am facing is on add an option so that end user can filter data via data range or like say today or last one month etc.

That way the chart will be way more interactive and useful.

what would be the option to do that. i am using startBootStrap template which contains libraries for morris charts.

Answer (score -1):

i used http://www.daterangepicker.com/#ex4 and linked it to my rest call to filter data

here is the brief code

```
 function cb(start, end) {
        $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMM D, YYYY'));
        //alert(start.format('MMM D, YYYY'));
        $.ajax({ url: 'http://127.0.0.1:7101/MUDRESTService/rest/v1/msessionchart?onlyData=true&fields=Sessionlength,Sessiontime&limit=10',             
             type: 'get',  
             dataType: 'json',    
             success: function(output) {
                console.log(output) ; 
                var ddata = JSON.stringify(output.items);
                console.log('vik says');
                console.log(ddata);
                var arr = JSON.parse(ddata);
                bar.setData(arr);
             }        
           });
    }

    cb(moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment());

    $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
        ranges: {
           'Today': [moment(), moment()],
           'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
           'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
           'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
           'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
           'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        }
    }, cb);
```